# Regex to substitute an extension's first occurrence from the right side

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following files

```
In [2]: os.listdir()                                                                                              
Out[2]: ['brmdh.md', '.DS_Store', 'breakfast.md', 'test.sh', 'bmdt.md']
```

I'd like to change the extensions from .md to .py, leave others unchanged

please notice 'brmdh.md', 'bmdt.md'

I tried to handle one of them

```
re.sub("a patter specify .md at the end of string", "py", 'brmdh.md')
```

I am unable to complete it and find it handy if there's a sub from the right side to replace "md"'s first occurrence.

```
re.rsub(r"md{1}", "py", 'brmdh.md')
```

Is it possible to get it working using lib re?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
re.sub(r'(?P<file_name>.*)\.md$', '\g<file_name>.py', 'hello.md')  # hello.py
```